# notifyDataSetChanged() in BaseAdapter not working correctly

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ListView` with my `Adapter`. In the list view I have implemented `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to know which item is being touched so to launch a custom dialog for every item in my List.

When I dismiss the dialog I want to update the item in the List

```
public class ClickListenerListPreferences implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final int POSICION_INFORMACION = 2;
    private static final int MIN_VALUE_NUMBER_PICKER = 10;
    private static final int MAX_VALUE_NUMBER_PICKER = 120;

    private Context context;
    private static ListSettingsViewAdapter adapter;

    public ClickListenerListPreferences(Context ctx, ListSettingsViewAdapter pAdapter){
        context = ctx;
        adapter = pAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(position == ListSettingsViewAdapter.POSICION_NOMBRE){
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_text_view, null);
            Button botonAceptar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.boton_aceptar);
            Button botonCancelar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.boton_cancelar);

            botonAceptar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_selector);
            botonCancelar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_selector);

            final EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialog);

            AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                builderDialog.setView(v);

            final AlertDialog dialog = builderDialog.show();

            botonAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

                    String nombre = editText.getText().toString();

                    editor.putString("nombre", nombre);
                    boolean funciona = editor.commit();

                    adapter.actualizarNombre(nombre);

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            botonCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
        else if(position == ListSettingsViewAdapter.POSICION_DURACION_ENTRENAMIENTO || position == ListSettingsViewAdapter.POSICION_DURACION_MI_ENTRENAMIENTO){

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_number_picker, null);

            SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.number_picker_dialog);

            picker.setMinValue(MIN_VALUE_NUMBER_PICKER);
            picker.setMaxValue(MAX_VALUE_NUMBER_PICKER);

            if(position == ListSettingsViewAdapter.POSICION_DURACION_ENTRENAMIENTO) {
                int duracion = sp.getInt("duracionEntrenamiento", 30);
                picker.setValue(duracion);
            }

            else if(position == ListSettingsViewAdapter.POSICION_DURACION_MI_ENTRENAMIENTO){
                int duracion = sp.getInt("duracionMiEntrenamiento", 30);
                picker.setValue(duracion);
            }

            Button botonAceptar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.boton_aceptar);
            Button botonCancelar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.boton_cancelar);

            botonAceptar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_selector);
            botonCancelar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_selector);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            builder.setView(v);

            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

            botonAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

                    if(position == ListSettingsViewAdapter.POSICION_DURACION_ENTRENAMIENTO) {
                        int valor = picker.getValue();
                        editor.putInt("duracionEntrenamiento", valor);
                        editor.commit();
                        adapter.actualizarDuracionEntrenamiento(valor);
                    }
                    else if(position == ListSettingsViewAdapter.POSICION_DURACION_MI_ENTRENAMIENTO){
                        int valor = picker.getValue();
                        editor.putInt("duracionMiEntrenamiento", valor);
                        editor.commit();
                        adapter.actualizarDuracionEntrenamiento(valor);
                    }

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        botonCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        }
    }
}
```

And my Adapter class:

```
public class ListSettingsViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static Vector<ItemPreference> itemsPreference;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater; //Para acceder al los elementos del list_item.xml

    private final int PRIMER_SWITCH = 5; //Posicion en la lista del primer Switch
    private final int SEGUNDO_SWITCH = 8; //Posicion en la lista del segundo Switch

    public static final int POSICION_NOMBRE = 1;
    public static final int POSICION_DURACION_ENTRENAMIENTO = 4;
    public static final int POSICION_DURACION_MI_ENTRENAMIENTO = 7;

    public ListSettingsViewAdapter(Context ctx, Vector<ItemPreference> pItemsPreference){
        super();
        context = ctx;
        itemsPreference = pItemsPreference;
    }

    @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return itemsPreference.size(); //Cantidad de elementos dentro de la lista. Si no le damos la cantidad, la lista aparecera vacia
        }

    @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

    @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //Accedo al .xml del item de la lista que voy a inflar
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = null;

            if(itemsPreference.elementAt(position).getTipoLayout() == 0){ //Layout 2 TextViews
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_text_view, parent, false);
                v.setTag(position);

                TextView titulo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
                TextView subtitulo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo);

                titulo.setText(itemsPreference.elementAt(position).getTitular());
                subtitulo.setText(itemsPreference.elementAt(position).getDescripcion());
            }

            return v;
        }

    public void actualizarNombre(String nombre){
        itemsPreference.elementAt(POSICION_NOMBRE).setDescripcion(nombre);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void actualizarDuracionEntrenamiento(int duracion){
        itemsPreference.elementAt(POSICION_DURACION_ENTRENAMIENTO).setDescripcion(Integer.toString(duracion));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void actualizarDuracionMiEntrenamiento(int duracion){
        itemsPreference.elementAt(POSICION_DURACION_MI_ENTRENAMIENTO).setDescripcion(Integer.toString(duracion));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

When I call my `adapter.actualizarNombre(nombre);` in my `ClickListener`, it is correctly updated in my `ListView` when I dismiss the dialog. But when it enters into the `elseif()` and I call `adapter.actualizarDuracionEntrenamiento(valor);` it is being executed but nothing happens and what most surprises me is that if I move `adapter.actualizarDuracionEntrenamiento(valor);` to the same position of `adapter.actualizarNombre(nombre);` it is correctly updated.

Do you have any idea of what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't speak your language but it seems in your dialog's click listener, when the position is POSICION_DURACION_MI_ENTRENAMIENTO, you are calling

```
adapter.actualizarDuracionEntrenamiento(valor);
```

instead of

```
adapter.actualizarDuracionMiEntrenamiento(valor);
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I was getting crazy debugging my code and i could not find the error. Now it works great :)